# How to show a content only in front page in WordPress using PHP logic?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, logic, conditional-statements

I have multiple WordPress site where there is an image of a logo attached to bottom of every page. Now I need it to appear only in the front page and not in the other pages.

What PHP logic and code should I use to solve this problem? I don't want to use the Widget Logic plugins. Just want to edit the PHP logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) function to check if you are on homepage.
If you use `is_home` it will return true on blog page only.

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stanimir. "if ( is_front_page() ) {" worked while "if(is_home()) {" didn't work. :)

Comment: Great! Consider upvote or accepting the answer so, it can help other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe WordPress provides is_home function which returns true if page is set as home/front page. Have a look in here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

```
if(is_home()) {
    //my code attaching logo
}
```

In WordPress you could actually find a hook/action for a footer display and do it there. You could as well add it site-wide using apache.

Answer (score 0):

Step :1 Check post is home page

```
if(is_home()) {

}
```

Step :2 Create Shortcode for the display purpose

```
function mylogo() {
    if(is_home()) {
        echo '<img src="mylogo.png" alt="">';
    }       
}
add_shortcode('mylogo','mylogo');
```

Step :3 open footer.php or where even you want to display just use this shortcode,

**In php filecode,**

```
do_shortcode('mylogo');
```

**In WYSWYG,**

```
['mylogo']
```